# Does "gaping question" make sense?

Tags: clauses

The New York Times is running an article on the terror attacks in France that begins with "The government faced gaping questions over its failure..."

Does the phrase "gaping question" actually make sense?

Comment: It's a collocation: a "gaping hole", a "gaping problem".  *Gaping* refers to "a serious issue that must not go unaddressed".

Comment: I understand the intention. The issues being questioned are gaping.  But is the question itself gaping?

Comment: When "gaping" and "question" are used figuratively, yes.  A "question", to a newspaper, is someone else's problem, lapse, failure, misdeed, etc.

Comment: @TRomano 'Gaping question' is not a collocation if one goes by the scarcity of Google hits for the string (contrast 'gaping hole'), and its non-inclusion in the English Collocations Dictionary online. I myself wouldn't consider the pairing common enough to qualify as a collocation. And the meaning of 'gaping' is 'deep and wide', which doesn't really fit 'question'. Yes, the meaning may be broadening to include 'serious', but I'd consider this a fringe usage at the moment.

Comment: It's nonsense. A question can't gape.

Comment: "fills a much needed gap in the literature"

Comment: @Patrick Wood. And you can't boil a kettle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Gaping question* is not common, and its meaning could easily be misinterpreted, but neither of the individual definitions is offended by the coupling:

***[gaping](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gaping)***

> ADJECTIVE
>
> (Of a hole, wound, etc.) wide open:

***[question](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/question)***

> NOUN
>
> 1. A sentence worded or expressed so as to elicit information:
>
> 1.1 A doubt about the truth or validity of something:
>
> 2. A matter requiring resolution or discussion:

The word picture of the etymology might be particularly consistent with the situation referenced:

> early 13c., from an unrecorded Old English word or else from Old Norse
>   gapa "to open the mouth, gape,"
>
> common Proto-Germanic (cognates:
>   Middle Dutch, Dutch gapen, German gaffen "to gape, stare," Swedish
>   gapa, Danish gabe), from PIE *ghai- (see gap). Related: Gaped; gaping.
>   As a noun, from 1530s.

With gaping the past participle of ***[gape](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gape)***:

> VERB
>
> 1. Stare with one’s mouth open wide in amazement or wonder:

Some possible (if improbable) interpretations:

> - The government faced *wide open questions* over its failure...
> - The government faced *wide open doubts* over its failure...
> - The government faced *wide open matters for discussion* over its failure...
> - The government faced *questions from gaping people* over its    failure...
> - The government faced *doubts from gaping people* over its    failure...
> - The government faced *questions (which made people gape)* over its    failure...
> - The government faced *doubts (which made people gape)* over its    failure...

The first two interpretations seem intuitive enough. On its face the adjective *gaping* seems more appropriate in describing the ***failures*** than the questions, but examining the [specific uses of *gaping question*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gaping%20question&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgaping%20question%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate an interpretation hovering between *serious question* and *wide open question* with a hint of *open-mouthed amazement*.

***[The Heart of the Hills](https://books.google.com/books?id=5WZuBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT180&dq=%22gaping%20question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_pexVPjBMoiLyAS5o4K4Ag&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22gaping%20question%22&f=false)*** from 1913:

> In the Bluegrass it was criticism of Colonel and Mrs. Pendleton, their
>   indifference, carelessness, blindness, ***a gaping question*** of their
>   sanity at the risk of even a suspicion that such a mating might be
>   possible...

***[Peace Shall Destroy Many](https://books.google.com/books?id=cfYjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gaping%20question%22&dq=%22gaping%20question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DpuxVNvNFsqiyATuy4G4DQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBTh4)***, 1962

> There was a scurry at the door, and all turned to see Pete Block slam
>   the door behind him. Thorn saw Herb before him, the bachelor's crooked
>   face registering nothing but ***a gaping question***, and then he
>   noticed that Hank was gone also.

***[American Foreign Policy, Basic Documents](https://books.google.com/books?id=3LPZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gaping%20question%22&dq=%22gaping%20question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wZmxVMScCMGkyASIwYCgCA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBTha)***, 1982:

> You're also stating that they must pursue a specific code of conduct
>   in their internal affairs if they are going to get any place with U.S.
>   aid or assistance. If you're not specific about this, it leaves a very
>   ***gaping question***.

***[The Navy Justice Collection: Treason, Hostage, Defiance](https://books.google.com/books?id=IcqbAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT587&dq=%22gaping%20question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_pexVPjBMoiLyAS5o4K4Ag&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gaping%20question%22&f=false)*** from 2014:

> But the big, ***gaping question*** left in the government's case was, why?
>
> Why would a Muslim intentionally attack his own holy site?

Gaping questions seem to be common in government circles.

Comment: The two quotes use "question" in the meaning of doubt, and "gaping question" (as great doubt) makes sense in those cases. I don't think  doubt is the meaning of "question" in the NY Times article, although it could be.  Nice answer, thanks.